# Calculate div width and insert clear div

Tags: jquery

I have this code.

```
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

The children of the container DIV have different heights, which means I get float issues. I would like some jquery that looks at the childrens widths, calculates them, and if they are 100% or close to, a div with a clear class is added to the markup.

However, I have no clue how to start. The divs are all in percentage.

**UPDATE:
For responsive stuff I changed the code a bit, so it can be added or removed. Also I had one of the javascript guys in the company optimize it**

```
$(window).load(function () {
    clearContext();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    clearContext();
});



function clearContext(){
    $('.contextElements .spot').addLineBreak(); //Choose target
}



// PLUGIN
(function($) {
    $.fn.addLineBreak = function() {
        var $this = this,
            minLeft = 0;

        //clear
        $('.removeDiv').remove();

        minLeft = $this.first().position().left;

        $this.each(function() {
            var $elm = $(this),
                position = $elm.position();

            if (position.left > minLeft && $elm.prev().position().left >= position.left) {        
                $elm.before('<div class="clear removeDiv"></div>');
            }
        });

        return this;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Define what 'close to' means, under your circumstances. And where do you want the clearing div added?

Comment: Using jQuery/javascript to solve layout problems is the first step down a long dark path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a similar purpose I've written this plugin a while ago:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.extend({
    addLineBreak: function(css) {
      var minLeft = $(this).position().left;

      return $(this).each(function() {
        var position = $(this).position();
        if (position.left > minLeft && $(this).prev().position().left >= position.left) {
          $(this).css(css);
        }
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
$('.container div').addLineBreak({clear: 'left'});
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/HLXvy/

Comment: Looks exactly like what I need. I get a error in my console when I implement it. Any ideas what that could be
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of null"

Comment: @Johansrk Could be that your selector matches zero elements. It would then throw this error in the line `var minLeft = $(this).position().left;`.

Comment: I changed your plugin a bit, because IE7 has problems when it comes to clearing a div. So instead of adding a style clear, it adds a div with class clear

Answer (score 2):

1. Calculate `.container` width with `width()` or `outerWidth()` function
2. `$('.container div').each(function() {  })` calculate each div width
3. If width is what you need, with `.after()` function insert clear element

Hope this will help.